# I entered style in the HTML and "Inherited CSS" does not change

Tags: css, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

language : angular4 / typescript / css

Chrome Browser, DevelopeMode styles checked.
[image]

I definitely coded styles.

But I do not know why it does not change.

```
<style>  
.k-grid, td{
   white-space: nowrap;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.k-grid-content, .k-grid-content-locked, .k-pager-wrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Does inherit css have to be used in any other way?

Comment: Inherit will only inherit from the parent element. (Maybe I missunderstood you. can you also add the HTML code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** I understand your question correctly and you're trying to reset the white-space to normal, it seems that you have an specificity issue, as `div.k-grid-content.k-virtual(...)` is much more specific than simply `.k-grid-content`, so the first rule will always be the one applied.

You need to beat the specificity of that rule to override it. Long way would be to use a longer chain, lazy way would be to `!important` your rule, correct way would be to re-write that extremely over-qualified first rule to something quite less specific.